# Removed sink, now what?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, sink

We've decided to replace the sink (which was way too small) with one from Ikea.

This is how it looks after the removal:
[image]

Now for the problems:

- The sink that was there before was a free-hanging one, the new one isn't. That's why there are these two big screws on top. 
   We tried to remove them with a pipe wrench, but it didn't even move a bit. What should we do with them? Cut them off with an angle grinder?
- The tap supply seems to be too high. It's upper border is touching with the sink's porcelain. Is there a way to move it down somehow?

Comment: What is that kind of trap called? I've never seen it before.

Comment: @ArgentoSapiens: No idea. I think it's a standard European one ...

Comment: A bottle trap, common when you have exposed waste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say the supply line "upper border" is touching the sink porcelain... Does that mean that if you raised the new sink an inch or two the porcelain would clear the supply lines?  If so I'd go that route.  I know many IKEA vanities stand on legs; if that's the case with yours perhaps you could replace them with taller legs, even if you have to make them yourself.  If it's not on legs the vanity can be shimmed up and the shims hidden with base molding.  As @shirlock mentioned pics of what you're installing would be helpful.

And as for the mounting studs, if you don't end up needing to open the wall, and as long as they're going to be covered by the new sink, I'd cut them off with an angle grinder as you suggested.

Comment: Yes, that's the way we went now. However, we couldn't find a screw that fitted, so we put onto four washmachine silencers. Ugly, but it works ;-).

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, you have gotten yourself into a situation that is most likely going to require opening the wall to replumb the water supplies and possibly the drain. If you have access to the back through another wall, then you will not have to remove some tiles. If you don't have access, then you have to open it up from the front, not an easy job. The support bolts are probably secured to a horizontal stud and bolted on both sides of the stud to prevent them from turning.

Is it possible to see a pic of what you took out and what you want to install?

Comment: Even if you do not remove the tiles, you will be left with holes in the tiles in a rather glaring place. A frustrating thing about renovation is it sometimes spreads, forcing you to do more than you really wanted to do.

Comment: Presumably the holes will be covered by the new vanity & sink (assuming that's what's replacing the bolted-on sink).

Comment: Although we would have access through the back, that's not an option for us. So we just put the new washbin in front and it's done!

We already got rid of the old washbin, so there's no pics.

Answer (score 5):

Screw two nuts in counter direction, then try and unscrew the screws with a wrench positioned on the nut, closer to the wall.

Something like this, if You haven't already destroyed the bolt:
[image]

Comment: Ow! That's how you do it. Duh! Well, we just sawed them off with a handsaw. But thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the water supply down will most likley need the tiles removing and quite allot of destructive wall work and pipe rework required.

I would suggest maybe trying to put the new sink slightly higher(drill some new holes above the existing ones, and grind the old ones flush to the walls, taking care not to grind the tiles. trying to remove the existing threaded studs might cause damage to the wall and tiles) if possible at all. If you have a pedastal one then you might get away with it.

Here are some solution to decrease destructive reinstallation

Use a Copper to Flexi pipe. This pipe easily welds on to the ends that you have there and will conenct to any tap easily.

[image]

You can use a 90degree copper adapter to point away from the base possibly giving you some extra needed.

[image]

You also can use copper male adapters to manipulate the pipes.

[image]

One thing I learn in all the years of home building and DIY is that destruction should always be the last possible choice, even if it's cheaper because most of the time using some clever combinations can save you days of brick work, plastering etc. etc. etc. ...

Comment: Nice solution! And yes, we went for the 'better not mess with the tiles' solution, by just covering it up :-).

Comment: I'd love to see you weld that flex hose onto the pipe....